# No datas coming from Firebase : Todo list

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I'm really angry against myself because I can't figure it out. My problem is I need to use firebase for a big project, but it's my first time with it, and with noSQL. So I started the Todo list tutorial using ionic creator (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrwrZBBOiP8&list=PLG71uQ6L5PWNOsIDFrP3X-_s-W4T6vBzP).

My problem is, I set the database like this :

[image]

Tried, like that :

[image]

Here you can find the service I use and how I call it on todos pages :

```js
//todos.js file

angular.module('todos', ['firebase'])

.run(function(){

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "//",
    authDomain: "//",
    databaseURL: "//",
    storageBucket: "//",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

})


.service("Todos", ["$firebaseArray", function($firebaseArray){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("todos");
    var items = $firebaseArray(ref);
    
    var todos = {
        items: items,
        addItem: function(title){
            items.$add({
                title: title,
            })
        },
        setFinished: function(item, newV){
            item.finished = newV;
            items.$save(item);
        }
    }
    return todos;
}]);
```

```js
// todos page

function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos) {

    $scope.items = Todos.items;
}


// Finished item page

function ($scope, $stateParams, Todos) {
    
    $scope.items = Todos.items;
}


// todo item page

function ($scope, $stateParams) {

    $scope.itemid = $stateParams.items;

}
```

And I still have no datas coming from Firebase, I tried to print "Todos.items" in the console, but there are too many fields in this array, I can't find my datas. When starting the app, I have these blanks pages but no errors :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If just want to read info use $http to your firebase url.

```
var url = 'https://test-data.firebaseio.com/data.json';
                    $http.get(url).then(function(response){conole.log(response.data)});
```

**Add firebase permission to read.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Mmmh, the point is I'll need to write too into the base. I tried to add these two lines in my service, but I got an Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined, $http is not an intern variable of ionic ?

Comment: No, you need to inject $http.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your Firebase project/database/rules and allow read option.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```